# Getting first entry of each unique combination of fields from elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an elasticsearch database that I upload entries like this:

`{"s_food": "bread", "s_store": "Safeway", "s_date" : "2020-06-30", "l_run" : 28900, "l_covered": 1}`

When I upload it to elasticsearch, it adds an `_id`, `_type`, `@timestamp` and `_index` fields. So the entries look sort of like this:

`{"s_food": "bread", "s_store": "Safeway", "s_date" : "2020-06-30", "l_run" : 28900, "l_covered": 1, "_type": "_doc", "_index": "my_index", "_id": pe39u5hs874kee}`

The way that I'm using the elasticsearch database results in the same original entries getting uploaded multiple times. In this example, I only care about the `s_food`, `s_date`, and `l_run` fields being a unique combination. Since I have so many entries, I'd like to use the elasticsearch scroll tool to go through all the matches. So far in elasticsearch, I've only seen people use aggregation to get buckets of each term and then they iterate over each partition. I would like to use something like aggregation to get an entire entry (just 1) for each unique combination of the three fields that I care about (food, date, run). Right now I use aggregation with a scroll like so:

```html
GET /my-index/_search?scroll=25m
{
 size: 10000,
 aggs: {
  foods: {
   terms: {
    field: s_food
   },
    aggs: {
      dates: {
        terms: {
          field: s_date
        },
        aggs: {
          runs: {
            terms: {
              field: l_run
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is only giving me the usual bucketed structure that I don't want. Is there something else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use top-hits aggregation with `size: 1`. Read more about top-hits aggregation [here](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html).

The query would look like this:

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "aggs": {
    "foods": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "s_food"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dates": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "s_date"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "runs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "l_run"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "topOne": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will this work with the scroll functionality? I need to get more than 10,000 entries which has posed a problem for aggregation.